# KeyEvents not firing in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

My view consists of a bunch of `Tile` objects which extend `Stackpane` and a menubar with menu items. I'm trying to control what's happening with the tiles with my arrow keys but i can't get the events to fire.

I can't add an event handler to the scene of the view because it doesn't have a scene when it's being initialized.

```
view.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        switch (event.getCode()) {
            case UP:
                event.consume();
                System.out.println("Test");
                model.tryMove(Richting.OMHOOG);
                break;
            case DOWN:
                event.consume();
                System.out.println("Test");
                model.tryMove(Richting.LINKS);
                break;
            case LEFT:
                event.consume();
                System.out.println("Test");
                model.tryMove(Richting.LINKS);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                event.consume();
                System.out.println("Test");
                model.tryMove(Richting.RECHTS);
                break;
        }
        model.checkDone();
    }
});
```

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Comment: Nodes that do not contain the focus don't receive key events...

Comment: "I can't add an event handler to the scene of the view because it doesn't have a scene when it's being initialized." So add the event handler to the scene when and where you do create the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot I added this line `view.setOnMouseClicked(event -> view.requestFocus());`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StackPane view = new StackPane();
        view.setPrefSize(200,200);
        view.setOnMouseClicked(event -> view.requestFocus());
        view.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            switch (event.getCode().toString()) {
                case "UP":
                    event.consume();
                    System.out.println("UP");
//                        model.tryMove(Richting.OMHOOG);
                    break;
                case "DOWN":
                    event.consume();
                    System.out.println("DOWN");
//                        model.tryMove(Richting.LINKS);
                    break;
                case "LEFT":
                    event.consume();
                    System.out.println("LEFT");
//                        model.tryMove(Richting.LINKS);
                    break;
                case "RIGHT":
                    event.consume();
                    System.out.println("RIGHT");
//                        model.tryMove(Richting.RECHTS);
                    break;
            }
//                model.checkDone();
        });


        Scene scene = new Scene(view);

        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```